# Testing SQL procedure call in repository pattern

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, moq

Can you advice me how to write unit test / create Mock for this class ?

```
public class LoadRepository :Repository<Load, LoadModel>,ILoadRepository
 {
    IUSCanadaCityStateRepository _USCanadaCityStateRepository;
    public LoadRepository(DbContext dbContext, IUSCanadaCityStateRepository  USCanadaCityStateRepository) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _USCanadaCityStateRepository = USCanadaCityStateRepository;
    }        
    public int GetPickUpLocations(int loadId)
    {
        var count = _dbSet.FromSql("SELECT COUNT(LocationID) as locationCount FROM vPickupLoc WHERE vPickupLoc.LoadID = @p0", loadId).ToArray();
        return count[0].LoadLocations.Count;
    }


    public LoadCarrierInfo UpdateCarrierInfo(LoadCarrierInfo loadCarrierInfo)
    {

        return _dbSet.FromSql("UpdatePickCarrier @CarrierID,@LoadID, @Primary,@AssistingPortalID,@AssistingEmployeeID",
                    new SqlParameter("LoadID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = loadCarrierInfo.LoadId },
                    new SqlParameter("Dispatcher", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = loadCarrierInfo.Dispatcher },
                    new SqlParameter("EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1 }, // logged in Employee instead
                    new SqlParameter("AssistingPortalID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = loadCarrierInfo.AssistingPortalId },
                    new SqlParameter("AssistingEmployeeID", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = loadCarrierInfo.AssistingEmployeeId })
                    .Select(x=>new LoadCarrierInfo { }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

Unfortunatelly all the methods are wrote in this manner and I'm not sure how much testable could be.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The point of unit test is not to test against the database but the logic of your code. When you put database stuff into unit testing it is not unit test anymore it's integration test.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to mock or if you want to test the SQL procedure? Those are mutually exclusive. It should be easy to mock assuming the methods are from `ILoadRepository` and not `Repository`.

Comment: I want to mock the ILoadRepository if that would be possible - however, without running the procedures

Answer (score 0):

you can use a mocking framework like [Nsubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/). Use it like this,

```
var loadRepo = Substitute.For<ILoadRepository>();
```

then you can inject the mock into the consumer of the ILoadRepository. Then you can mock methods like this,

```
var returnValue = new LoadCarrierInfo();
loadRepo.UpdateCarrierInfo(Arg.Any<LoadCarrierInfo>).Returns(returnValue );
```

This will return `returnValue` object for `UpdateCarrierInfo` method call with any argument.

There are more options provided in the documentation of [Nsubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/).